# Tuning Linux's IPv6 stack

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, tuning

I'm working on a Linux network deice, and there are some TCP/IP settings that don't seem to have IPv6 equivalents. IP forwarding is a common setting, and available in both stacks

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding
```

But these are examples of some setting I would need to support IPv6

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem
```

`ip_nonlocal_bind` is pretty critical, and settings for TCP TIME_WAIT sockets are seemingly missing.

Pointers to kernel/iproute documentation which I may have missed would be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that at least some (all?) of these features just haven't been implemented.

[Here is a recent attempted patch to add ipv6_nonlocal_bind](http://marc.info/?l=linux-netdev&m=127818997108725&w=2), with some issues later in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

http://kb.pert.geant.net/PERTKB/LinuxOSSpecific suggests:

> Note that although some of these parameters have ipv4 in their names, they apply equally to TCP over IPv6.

I have not tested myself whether it is true.

Comment: Some of them are easy to test. I can confirm that `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` also affects IPv6. But `net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind` does not affect IPv6. That does not mean that nonlocal binds are not implemented for IPv6 though, it is just controlled through a per socket option rather than through a systemwide setting.